# Inheritance, leaving crypto to a child, drip by drip

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, inheritance

How would be best to lock,up some eth (or other crypto, BTC?) for example, for my sons future ? Ie so that his wallet receives a certain percentage of the contents of my account over a certain period of time. For example 1% every month from when he reaches 18 and stops and sends the remaining balance when he’s 50 for example ?

Other ideas welcome !

My sons a high functioning autistic child and I plan on teaching him his wallet address soon. He’s up for it:-)

Comment: A smart contract cannot execute itself. You could use some external tool to call a contract periodically to execute a function.

Comment: Ah that’s interesting. I’d have thought that would be possible with some kind of time stamp on the block. How about on a  proof of history blockchain? 
If not how would I secure an external tool to trigger payments?